# use of submitButton to open a dialog i.e change 'CActiveForm' into dialog : yii

Tags: yii, dialog, submit-button

I have used submitButton in my view form and on click of the button I have to open a dialog i.e another view form. How can I achieve that?
    My code for submit button is:

```
<?php
echo CHtml::submitButton('Mail to Client' ,array(
 'onclick'=>'js:act()',
'id'=>'$model->marketing_id','name' => 'ApproveButton' ,'class'=>'btn btn-success'));?>
```

From javascript method `act()` I have called my controller.this button is in my admin form. The code of controller to call another view is:

```
$this->render('_compose',array('mailList'=>$mailList,'model'=>$model),FALSE,true);
```

This `_compose` view, I have to open in dialog form. My `_Compose` form code is :

```
<?php

$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
    'id'=>'mydialog',
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Mail to client',
        'autoOpen'=>true,
    ),
));
?>

<div class="form wide">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'reply-form1',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'), // ADD THIS
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.For multiple recipients please seperate by comma</p>

    <?php  echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>



    <div class="row col2">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email_from'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email_from',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'readonly'=>'readonly')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'email_from'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row col2">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email_to'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email_to',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'readonly'=>'readonly')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'email_to'); ?>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'message'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'message',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'message'); ?>
    </div>


<div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Send' : 'Send',array('class' => 'btn')); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>
 <?php $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
 echo CHtml::link('Open Dialog', '#', array(
   'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;',
));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [CJuiDialog](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiDialog) for this:

```
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
    'id'=>'mydialog',
    'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Mail to client',
        'autoOpen'=>false,
    ),
));

<div class="form wide">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'reply-form1',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'), // ADD THIS
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.For multiple recipients please seperate by comma</p>

    <?php  echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    <div class="row col2">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email_from'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email_from',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'readonly'=>'readonly')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'email_from'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row col2">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email_to'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email_to',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'readonly'=>'readonly')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'email_to'); ?>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'message'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'message',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'message'); ?>
    </div>


<div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Send' : 'Send',array('class' => 'btn')); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>

$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
/** End Widget **/
echo CHtml::link('Open Dialog', '#', array(
   'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;',
));
```

Comment: i tried your code its not working. Should i change code in controller too?

Comment: there are no errors.but all the labels  and input fields are gone

Comment: the form opens in new tab.i want this form in dialog form when the button in another form gets clicked.

Comment: @ManiRatna When you click that button call a controller's action, render the above view and change the line `'autoOpen'=>false,` to `'autoOpen'=>true,`

Comment: On click of button i have called my controller's function and the render of view has been done too. i tried 'autoOpen'=>true but still doesnot work.the form opens in new tab

Comment: @ManiRatna Can you update your question with the code you're trying ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96762/discussion-between-criesto-and-mani-ratna).